# Create iOS client server app. ASIFormDataRequest issues

Tags: ios, json, post, client-server, asihttprequest

My question is:
How can I create the same request as below using `ASIFormDataRequest`and second as I think I need to parse JSON from response.

```
http://exampledomain.com/mobile_api/register/?client=iphone&info=A=iPhone/OS=5.1/C=UA&time=1342780143&udid=8b6f0cc104d137ae2e1730235f5664094b831122&version=1.0&secure=5444d72741bad93b916577d9297fa
```

Now I try to use code like this

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://test2.mafia.ua/mobile_api/register/";
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:@"iphone" forKey:@"client"];
    [request setPostValue:@"A=iPhone/OS=5.1/C=UA" forKey:@"info"];
    [request setPostValue:@"1342780143" forKey:@"time"];
    [request setPostValue:@"8b6f0cc104d137ae2e1730235f5664094b831122" forKey:@"udid"];
    [request setPostValue:@"1.0" forKey:@"version"];
    [request setPostValue:@"5444d72741bad93b916577d9297fa" forKey:@"secure"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

is this correct?

I implement delegate method also

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);

}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

}
```

In response I get this (I think this is JSON) if I use some browser.

{"status": "ok", "secret": "b82b7771f600772c2c5af903b117b5e", "client": "200004", "expires": "1345372850"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your data in POST fields (That's what `setPostValue:` does.)

You should be including them in your URL instead; try searching around for an easy way of building query parameters in a URL or just use something like stringWithFormat: and appropriate escaping.

Comment: thanks for response I try to use it as URL and I get Response 403 in response. But via browser (Google Chrome) I get json

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're still POSTing the data? Try using a GET from your app (use ASIHTTPRequest directly, perhaps?)